# Figuring out a substitute for an old amp capacitor #2

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, identification, vintage

What type are the yellow caps in the picture and what do I substitute them with?

[image]

Comment: These are most likely polystyrene caps. Are you sure they are broken? You can replace them by polypropylene caps, which generally have better specs than the old polystyrene ones.

Comment: Agree with Janka, looks like polystyrene caps, but these would not fail. Why replace them? Polystyrene has good performance.

Comment: So they are the same type as the silvery ones on this picture? 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BySG2ujLQzMWWW0wdzk5SndVdVU

Answer (score 1):

These are "film capacitors", usually rated for voltages suitable for vacuum tube amplifiers, 60V-200V-600V. They should be substituted with similar film capacitors, with any kind of dielectric, check with [DigiKey](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/capacitors/film-capacitors/62).

As I see, the caps are 0.047 uF 400VDC. So [this one](http://www.cde.com/resources/catalogs/150.pdf) would be a [perfect match](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cornell-dubilier-electronics-cde/150473K400DB/338-3299-ND/1930664).

Comment: it would be perfect if it was lower cost than $1.11 (10) and 16.5 mm L may need heat-shrink near adjacent caps

Comment: What is the difference between this one you recommend and the one recommended in the answer below yours ("This PP (polyprop) is smaller length 10mm , better performance than PE and cheaper. 0.58 or $5.88 for 10pc's

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/kemet/R75LF24704000K/399-13014-ND/5765881")

Answer (score 1):

This PP (polyprop) is smaller length 10mm , better performance than PE and cheaper. 0.58 or $5.88 for 10pc's

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/kemet/R75LF24704000K/399-13014-ND/5765881

[image]

Although radial, I believe this is a better Form, fit and function to drop in place (if needed)

Answer (score 1):

If they are not leaking DC, I would not concern myself with replacing them. If they are leaking DC, a typical replacement component is the Cornell Dubilier Type 150 Series Film Capacitors (formerly Mallory 150M).